# SQL - How to reorder a select query that uses the limit constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql statement that is working properly.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IS NULL ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20;
```

The query basically orders the table on date desc, and selects the 20 last records for which the field 'name' is null. The problem is that the query that is retrieved is ordered on date desc. It's logic of course... But what I would like, is that the 'output' is ordered on date asc. Thank you in advance for you replies. Cheers. Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    <your query>
)
ORDER BY date
```

Note: some SQL dialects require naming the subquery even if that name is not really used, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    <your query>
) T
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: Hello Branko. Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately this does not seem to work. MySql is telling: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Ok Branko, i added as t after the inner statement and it is working now. Thanks...

Comment: @Marc Yes, some DBMSes require this. When you ask a DBMS specific question, please include the DBMS in your question's tags. In this particular case, I wasn't aware you were targeting MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Use your query inside another query and order the outer query, which shall apply order again.