# How to get the end of an Ascending list of records with a limit?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, limit

I'm fighting a bit with a query I'm building. Let's say I've got a DB table like this:

```
id | some_string
----------------
1  | 'lala'
2  | 'jeje'
3  | 'poopoo'
4  | 'wicked wicked'
```

I now want to get the last three records (2, 3, and 4) ordered ascending by key. I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName LIMIT 3 ORDER BY id ASC
```

This gets me the first three records, instead of the last three. I can of course also use the query below, which gets me the correct records, but then I don't get them in Ascending order:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName LIMIT 3 ORDER BY id DESC
```

Does anybody know how I can get the last three records in an ascending order? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (
  select * from table_name order by id desc limit 3 
) last_3_rows
order by id
```

Comment: +1 - yes this is the answer. @Ravinder - can we use a query like the second query I had added in my answer?

Comment: No. you can't in MySQL. That syntax is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

This is a query inside another query. that reorders your query.([SQL - How to reorder a select query that uses the limit constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189893/sql-how-to-reorder-a-select-query-that-uses-the-limit-constraint))

```
select * FROM (SELECT * FROM tableName LIMIT 3 ORDER BY id DESC) AN_UNUSUAL_NAME ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort on the resulting result set ie. do a `select * from (<your query here>) order by id`